# Silverlight app hangs at 100%

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, mvvm

I have seen that related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014365/silverlight-hangs-at-100-loaded) but it didn't helped. I have a simple silverlight mvvm application for which I have created custom views and viewmodels and I have set the main view as rootlayout. Compiles succesfully, but when I hit run, the app hangs at 100%. I have placed breakpoints all over the app (in the views and in the app.cs) but it never reaches them. I'ved also replaced the mainview with a simple page with only a simple button on it (and set it as rootlayout), but still it hangs at 100% (I'ved thought that my view caused the problem, but it doesn't work on simple pages as well).

Is there any way to view the exceptions? Or something that I am missing...??
Silverlight version 3.

Thanks in advance
Tamash

Comment: If you pause execution through Visual Studio, where does it break to?

Comment: It shows me a "No Source Available" page.

Comment: And if you turn on Break on Exceptions for all thrown Common Language Runtime Exceptions (not just User-unhandled) and try to run, does it break with some exception detail?

Comment: Same thing. It doesn't show any exception. Just hangs at 100%. Doesn't reach the Page1 contructor breakpoint (the rootlayout).

Comment: I am very embarrassed. I have done some checks before setting the rootLayout and the checks failed. Thats why it didn't worked even for a simple page. Back on my feet now and hope it helps someone.